# How to get a model id from inside a validation method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In one of my validations, I would like to make sure that the user date range input is not overlapping with existing stored date-ranges:

```
class Timecard < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :does_not_intersect_with_existing_timecards

  def does_not_intersect_with_existing_timecards
    if from_date && to_date &&
      !Timecard.where("? <= to_date AND ? >= from_date", from_date, to_date).empty?
      errors.add(:from_date, "must not intersect with existing timecards")
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that this validation will fail if called from an `update` method (as the `where` clause will find the record currently being updated in the database). I do not want to only validate `on: :create`, since the user may edit the date range.

**How can I exclude the current model from the validation query?**

I don't seem to have access to `id` or `@id` from within the validation method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this

```
def does_not_intersect_with_existing_timecards
  if self.new_record?  
     errors.add(:from_date, "must not intersect with existing timecards") if from_date && to_date && !Timecard.where("? <= to_date AND ? >= from_date ", from_date, to_date).empty?
  else
     errors.add(:from_date, "must not intersect with existing timecards") if from_date && to_date && !Timecard.where("? <= to_date AND ? >= from_date AND id != ?", from_date, to_date, self.id).empty?
  end

end
```

OR

```
def does_not_intersect_with_existing_timecards
   errors.add(:from_date, "must not intersect with existing timecards") if from_date && to_date && !Timecard.where("#{self.new_record? || 'id != ' + self.id.to_s} AND ? <= to_date AND ? >= from_date ", from_date, to_date).empty?
end
```

Comment: Beautiful. Went with the first option, even though it's not the most DRY (second option didn't work in some cases). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before_save` hook instead of `validation`

Comment: It's a good idea, but I preferred staying performing validations with the `validate` mechanism. I got the impression from the examples in the RoR guides that the hooks are mostly used for input sanitation and conversion rather than validation.